# Are Computation Expressions an alternative approach to Aspect-oriented Programming?

Tags: f#, computation-expression

Are Computation Expressions an alternative approach to Aspect-oriented Programming?

Is this F#'s solution for managing cross-cutting concerns.

I viewed the following article and couldn't help but think of AOP (i.e. Aspect-oriented Programming).

In the [article](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/computation-expressions-intro/), the author provided an example of a Computation Expression that handled logging, but isolated the actual logging aspect of the code without obfuscating the main intent of the business logic.

Are my thoughts accurate?

Comment: You can't do e.g. `[<Serializable>]` with comp expressions.  You can't add multiple aspects in a single comp expression.  AOP is a bit grander; CE is a bit more precise.

Comment: @DaxFohl I agree that it'd be difficult to make something `[<Serializable>]` with F# computation expressions, since this is already attribute-based, but computation expressions *can* be composed. It only requires a bit of work. Here's an example of composing Async and Either/Result: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2016/04/11/async-as-surrogate-io In Haskell, this can be done automatically with Monad Transformers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, monads are a great (and idiomatic) approach to cross-cutting concerns, among other things. A monad is a much more general concept, but one of the uses they can be put to is to model *effects* in systems.

In FP jargon, the word *effect* often implies a side-effect. Many cross-cutting concerns like logging, auditing, performance monitoring, caching, and metering all (by definition) have side-effects. Since they involve 'writing' data to a secondary stateful resource, they can be modelled with the State or Writer monads.

Other cross-cutting concerns like authentication, authorisation, and validation can often be addressed with the Reader monad (or, possibly, the State monad).

F# computation expressions provide syntactic sugar over monadic combinators (*return* and *bind*, essentially), the same way that Haskell's `do` notation does. Contrary to Haskell, however, you have to define the computation expression builder for a monad yourself, apart from the few already built in to the language (`async`, `seq`).

Using a monad to address a cross-cutting concern is a different approach than AOP.

In object-oriented programming, there are two fundamentally different takes on AOP:

- Decorators
- Compile-time weaving, of which the archetypical .NET example is PostSharp

As I explain in [my book](http://amzn.to/12p90MG), I consider compile-time weaving to be a heavy-handed and inflexible way to address the problem. Using a [Decorator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) is a more elegant and flexible way to achieve the same goal.

My motivation for that statement is my preference for *separation of concerns*.

If you use compile-time weaving in OOP, you'll often have code like this (C# example):

```
[Log]
public void SaveOrder(Order order)
{
    // Implementation goes here...
}
```

The problem here is that while the concerns are separated, they are still *coupled*. You can't decide *not* to log from `SaveOrder` unless you recompile.

Using a computation expression is a bit like that:

```
log { return saveOrder order }
```

Again, the cross-cutting concern is *compiled* together with the implementation.

Where the similarity ends, however, is that monadic combinators can be used to compose concerns together, which isn't easily possible with compile-time weaving. In OOP, you can't easily take a method that *doesn't* log, and 'magically' make it log when you compose your objects together.

Using monads, on the other hand, you *can* take a [pure function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) and compose it with a monadic context. Such later-bound logging is [structurally equivalent to using Decorators](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/11/30/to-log-or-not-to-log).

So, I'd consider it appropriate to use computation expressions for cross-cutting concerns, as long as you defer such code to the application's entry point (its [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot)).